# Interrupt python grpc client when receiving stream

Tags: python, queue, python-multithreading, grpc

I am playing a little bit with gRPC and I do not know how to close a connection between a client and the server when receiving a stream. Both the client and the server are written in Python.

For example, my server reads messages from a Queue and it yields each message. My idea is that the client subscribes to the server and starts receiving those messages.

My questions are:

- I would like to get the client killed whenever CTRL+C is pressed, but it gets stuck with the current code. How can it be done properly?
- How does the server realize that the client has stopped listening?

My nbi.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";
service Messenger {
    rpc subscribe(Null) return (stream Message) {}
}

message Null {}

message Message {
    string value = 1;
}
```

Python client:

```
import test_pb2_grpc as test_grpc
import test_pb2 as test
import grpc

def run():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:50051')
    stub = test_grpc.MessengerStub(channel)

    stream = stub.subscribe(test.Null())
    try:
        for e in stream:
            print e
    except grpc._channel._Rendezvous as err:
        print err
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        stub.unsuscribe(test.Null)
```

Python server:

```
import test_pb2_grpc as test_grpc
import test_pb2 as test
from Queue import Empty
import grpc

class Messenger(test_grpc.MessengerServicer):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def subscribe(self, request, context):
        while True:
            try:
                yield self.queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)
            except Empty:
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(e)
                break
        return
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to get the client killed whenever CTRL+C is pressed, but
>   it gets stuck with the current code. How can it be done properly?

The `KeyboardInterrupt` should be enough to terminate the client application. Probably the process is hanging on the `stub.unsubscribe`. If you use the client disconnection callback, perhaps you don't need to unsubscribe explicitly.

> How does the server realize that the client has stopped listening?

You can [add a callback to the context object](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.RpcContext.add_callback) that gets passed to your `Messenger.subscribe` method. The callback is called on client disconnection.

By the way, you can look in using [empty.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/empty.proto) in place of your `Null` type.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added the callback as you proposed and the server is now working properly. However, I am still unable to terminate the client.

Comment: Hmm, I just created the most basic unary-stream client as you have here for a service of mine. https://gist.github.com/markns/dd35f38d257f51255a8d82d86fb94813#file-gistfile1-txt Shuts down cleanly. There must be another thread blocking somewhere in your code

Comment: Okey, I think the problem only appears when using Python 2.7, I will try with Python 3... Thanks anyway.

Comment: What is `stub.unsubscribe(test.Null)`? That looks like something that would raise an `AttributeError`? If you want to cancel the in-flight RPC I would think that `stream.cancel()` would be the right code for that place?

Alternatively why not just drop the whole `except KeyboardInterrupt:` syntax element? It should be the case that the RPC gets cancelled when `stream` goes out of scope when the `run` function returns.